# How to combine a Video Overlay with clustered markers

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I adapted this tutorial:

https://github.com/asmaloney/Leaflet_Cluster_Example

It loads marker positions from a Json file.

now I want to integrate a VideoOverlay, which previously worked like this:

```
    var videoUrls = [
            'http://dominique.turzer.eu/media/mod_osmod/images/Film8.mp4'
    ];
        var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[ 41.92398333, 12.45647433], [ 41.863167640465, 12.502337292]]);

        var videoOverlay = L.videoOverlay( videoUrls, bounds, {
                opacity: 0.7,
            loop: false
        }).addTo(mapid);

        var videoElement = videoOverlay.getElement();

        L.DomEvent.on(videoElement, 'ended', function(){
            videoOverlay.remove();
        });
```

I can t figure out where to place/integrate this code. In my first try it was placed beneth "L.tileLayer", which now has the result that there are no maker (instead of many) anymore....  It might be the problem that the markerCluster example is for leaflet 0.7.7 and my VideoOverly worked with leaflet 1.3.1 -

My script file, is referenced with this line to the Body of my html file

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='maps/leaf-demo.js'></script>
```

The script file looks like that:

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [41.8939551, 12.479556],
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 13
});

L.tileLayer( 'https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
 subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo( map );

var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="leaf-demo.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'leaf-demo.js', '' );

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + 'images/pin24.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: myURL + 'images/pin48.png',
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14]
});

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i )
{
  var popup = markers[i].name +
              '<br/>' + markers[i].img;

  var m = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
                  .bindPopup( popup );

  markerClusters.addLayer( m );
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
```

And finaly there is an GeoJson file, which is structured like this:

```
var markers = [
  {
    "name":"Ponte Milvio",
    "lat":41.9361778,
    "lng":12.47166861,
    "img":'<img src="/images/banners/41-milvio.jpg" width=300 <p><strong style="color: #cd5c5c;">{loadposition position-12}</strong></p>',
  },{
```

When lading the page the Video should be played and after the Video has vanished there sould be the clustered markers, which finally lead to a popupcontaining a drawing from this place in Rome. It would also be wonderful if I could use custom image marker ikons showing the drawing and if I could add different Layers for different people contributing, but for the moment my goal is to combine the video Overlay with the clustered markers...

PS:
All this is going to be a website for an open source guideook about rome - a real physical book - which I am selling since 2009: The idea is that you can take the book to Rome to have notes and scetches. And who is returnig the book to me in 2020 become part of a collective exhibition:

http://stinanickel.org/index.php/de/component/spsimpleportfolio/item/2-roman-notes

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing the code that you have tried, even if it does not work. Make sure you include relevant within the body of your question, not only on an external server that may change in the future, making your question useless to future visitors.

Comment: Tanks! I added the code, please ask if there are more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any issue in integrating both the Video Overlay and the Leaflet.markercluster plugin.

However, in your code examples you use `mapid` and in another one `map`. Make sure you do not mix up your variables name.

Furthermore, your initial view might be quite zoomed in, displaying your cluster markers out of the initial view, making you believe they are not displayed.

Using a zoom of 11 for example shows that the markers are there:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [41.8939551, 12.479556],
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 11 //13
});

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo(map);

var videoUrls = [
  'http://dominique.turzer.eu/media/mod_osmod/images/Film8.mp4'
];
var bounds = L.latLngBounds([
  [41.92398333, 12.45647433],
  [41.863167640465, 12.502337292]
]);

var videoOverlay = L.videoOverlay(videoUrls, bounds, {
  opacity: 0.7,
  loop: false
}).addTo(map);

var videoElement = videoOverlay.getElement();

L.DomEvent.on(videoElement, 'ended', function() {
  videoOverlay.remove();
});

var markers = [{
  "name": "Ponte Milvio",
  "lat": 41.9361778,
  "lng": 12.47166861,
  "img": '<img src="/images/banners/41-milvio.jpg" width=300/> <p><strong style="color: #cd5c5c;">{loadposition position-12}</strong></p>',
}, {
  "name": "Ponte Milvio 2",
  "lat": 41.9361778,
  "lng": 12.47166861,
  "img": '<img src="/images/banners/41-milvio.jpg" width=300/> <p><strong style="color: #cd5c5c;">{loadposition position-12}</strong></p>',
}, {
  // Dummy marker to make sure it is visible on top of the video.
  "name": "dummy marker",
  "lat": 41.8939551,
  "lng": 12.479556,
  "img": "no img",
}];

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
  var popup = markers[i].name +
    '<br/>' + markers[i].img;

  var m = L.marker([markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {
      //icon: myIcon
    })
    .bindPopup(popup);

  markerClusters.addLayer(m);
}

map.addLayer(markerClusters);
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.markercluster assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: I thinks the problem was about defining the variables all in their logic chronology - and the zoom might have also been a problem - I learned a basic lesson today :-)... Thanks!